# Is there an alternative to hierarchical Spring security roles?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Can Spring roles only be defined in relative hierarchical terms as in this example?

Is there any way to define the roles in absolute terms?

```
<beans:bean id="roleHierarchy"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
        <beans:value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_ANONYMOUS
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in absolute terms"?

Comment: @Stephen C: With number values, for example.

Comment: but what is the point of doing that?

Comment: In general, roles aren't numerically mappable. (For example, being an admin on site A doesn't imply you're an admin on site B, or _vice versa_.) There's no global numeric mapping possible, and in fact no local one except on very simple sites either. But there is a local partial order very often, hence hierarchic roles at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help point you in the right direction: [here is an example](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/secure-rest) I wrote which uses explicitly defined roles to permit or reject access to protected data based on roles.

Note how the `EmployeeService` class checks the role and determines behavior absolutely.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!  I updated the link to the new location.